# asp.net $ is undefined after url rewriting which was working fine before

Tags: jquery, asp.net, url-rewriting, undefined

We have started implementing url rewriting. however it started giving $ is undefined error.

originally without any rewriting logic the project works perfectly fine with no error.

I have referenced the javascript file

```
<script src="~/JS/UI/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Am i missing anything? I have read so many posts on net and SO with similar issue and tried various things like ResolveURL and ../ , however none is working

Comment: Can you check if jquery is loaded. Check view Source for the page.

Comment: Change from `~/` symbol to `../` and check.... (or) try with `<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/JS/UI/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: What exactly do I look for after view source. fyi...we are using master page and several controls. I have included all js in master page file and we are building top menu dynamically using one of the superfish solution

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju: if you see my original post I already mentioned that ../ is not working

Comment: @vs: Oh.. okay.. can u try with this Url.Content like `<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/JS/UI/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`.. In my project i also included this _<rewrite>_ in web config, it's working fine for all js file..

Comment: @vs Try to use a tool to view if a source was loaded, in Safari/Chrome and IE if you hit F12 a developer tools will appear - Sources or Scripts will show you if jQuery was loaded. Firefox has the excellent Firebug addon that does the same thing (appears on F12).

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju: none is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the `~` works in the script tag; it's usually reserved for .net controls/user controls.

Remove it and try again

```
<script src="/JS/UI/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: right! you have to use strutures like the suggested above. If you want the parent directory you can write: ../JS/UI or ../../JS/UI

Answer (score 0):

in my project i am also using url rewriting and faced this problem and i solve this like this

in my master.cs page i create a function like this

```
public static string PageResolveUrls(System.Web.UI.Page pPage)
    {
        string strSiteUrl =System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["WebName"];
        string Url = pPage.Request.Url.ToString();
        string ReturnUrl = "";

        ReturnUrl = strSiteUrl;

        return ReturnUrl;
    }
```

and i use this this function in my master.aspx page like this

```
 <base href="<%=PageResolveUrls(Page) %>">
    </base>
<script src="<%=PageResolveUrl(Page,"JS/jQuery/jquery.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i think this will help you....

Comment: what is the use of string Url = pPage.Request.Url.ToString(); in your code your are simply assigning ReturnUrl = strSiteUrl;

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `../` instead of `~` symbol. It will solve the issue. Just start your `src=` with `../`.